# [Python-Webservice]: How to return and consume on XML format on Flask

Tags: python, web-services, flask

I am currently creating a RESTful webservice in python utilizing flask. Now on the client side that will use / implement the webservice APIs, I want to get the output in XML (or JSON) format. Do you have any ideas on how to do this? I already tried jsonify but no success. Also, i prefer an XML format in output, but again, I don't know how to do it. So I hope someone can give me ideas.

Below are dummy code snippets to hopefully clarify my question:

```
/*** webservice ***/
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
   return jsonify(message = "hello world!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()

/*** client code ***/
import urllib2
server = "http://localhost:5000/"
req = urllib2.Request(server)
# req has no data at all :(
```

Hoping to receive feedback. Than=ks in advance

Comment: Suggestion: use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) instead of urllib2, the API is much nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server code runs fine. You should test it with a normal web browser and you will see the json response. Your client code isn't complet. There my correction:

```
import urllib2
server = "http://localhost:5000/"
req = urllib2.Request(server)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print response.read()
```

A better way to do http requests in python is to use the [requests module](http://python-requests.org) which provides a very simple but very powerful api.

```
import requests
res = requests.get("http://localhost:5000/")
print res.text
```

To build xml response I would recommend [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) with his cool etree modul. There is also a etree modul in the standart lib under [`xml.etree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: thanks Jarus... I am quite familiar with lxml and use it on outputting text files. But how will I do this in rest API? should I convert the return to lxml format?

Comment: I would use JSON because it is also very poweful and in my eyes much cleaner than XML. If you want to use lxml than convert your etree to a xml string and return this by your view function.